# Brezis Exercise 3.7, the union of closed set and compact set in weak topology is closed.

Tags: functional-analysis

Exercise 3.7：Let $E$ be a banach space and let $A \subset E$ is a closed subset in the weak topology $\sigma(E,E^{*})$. Let $B\subset E$ is a compact subset in the weak topology $\sigma(E,E^{*})$.

> Blockquote 1.Prove that $A+B$ is closed in $\sigma(E,E^{*})$.

Following is the answer of Brezis:

1. Let $x \not\in A+B$. We shall construct a neighborhood $W$ of $0$ for $\sigma(E,E^{*})$ such that
   $$
    (x+W)\cap (A+B)=\emptyset.
   $$
   For every $y\in B$ there exists a convex neighborhood $V(y)$ of $0$ such that
   $$
   (x+V(y))\cap(A+y)=\emptyset.
   $$
   (Since $A+y$ is closed and $A\not\in A+y$).
   Cleary, 
   $$
   B\subset \cup_{y\in B}(y-\frac{1}{2}V(y)).
   $$

Until here, I don't konw why $B\subset \cup_{y\in B}(y-\frac{1}{2}V(y)).$ How to prove this?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3440427/in-a-topological-vector-space-if-a-is-compact-and-b-is-closed-then-ab-i

Comment: $0\in V(y)$ for all $y$.

Comment: thank you for your help!